# add where condition in jensseger mongodb with lookup

Tags: mongodb, laravel, eloquent

I have code like this:

```
$users = User::raw(function ($collection) use($profession, $userId, $skip, $pageSize) {
                return $collection->aggregate([
                            [
                                '$lookup' => [
                                    'from' => 'user_profile',
                                    'localField' => 'uid',
                                    'foreignField' => 'user_id',
                                    'as' => 'profile'
                                ]
                            ],

                            [
                                '$match' => [
                                    'profile.field_of_work' => $profession['id'],
                                    'uid' => ['$ne' => $userId]
                                ],
                            ],
                            ['$skip' => $skip],
                            ['$limit' => $pageSize]
                ]);
            });
```

from there, how to add where clause like this:

```
::where('name', 'like', '%test%');
```

I dont know how to using lookup in mongodb and I just know the basic pattern of eloquent.
Thank you

Comment: can you please post your collection and the version of mongodb you are using

Comment: it's already worked @AnthonyWinzlet, I just editing the `$match` conditions, thanks